# points won't move with erorr bars ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar, r-forestplot

I am trying to use color to show subgroups in my forest plot, but the estimates aren't aligned with the error bars. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
ggplot(data, aes(y = variable, x = variable, color = as.factor(subgroup)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conf_low, xmax = conf_high)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
facet_grid(~group)
```

The data is organized like this: 
There are four variables and 1 outcome. I am showing the result of linear regression (Beta and its confidence interval) and trying to separate them by gender and an additional subgroup.

```
Sample Dataset 

Indep. Var  Dep. Var   Sex      Subgroup.  Beta   conf_low. conf_high

Variable 1  Outcome   Male     Subgroup 1   0.5    -0.03       1.2
Variable 1  Outcome   Female   Subgroup 2   0.7     0.02       0.89
Variable 1  Outcome   Male.    Subgroup 1   5.43    1.20       6.00
Variable 1  Outcome   Female   Subgroup 2   1.22.   -0.56.     2.34
Variable 2. Outcome.  Male .....etc
```

I have tried `as.factor(subgroup)`. I'd like the error bars to be below each other for each of the four variables on the y axis.

[forest plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH94z.png)

I'd like it to look like the image below but with two colors. It was made with `ggforestplot`, but I'd like to keep mine with `ggplot` as it's easier with my data. Thanks!

[image: what its supposed to look like]

Comment: Welcome to So.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need to have your `data` so that we can test our suggested solutions.